# LuaLatex and MathTime Professional 2 (mixing font-types)

Tags: fonts, luatex, mtpro

I'm trying to use MathTime Professional 2 (mtpro2) and Times New Roman (the TrueType fonts bundled with Windows) with LuaLatex as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{      times.ttf}[
  BoldFont       = timesbd.ttf ,
  ItalicFont     = timesi.ttf ,
  BoldItalicFont = timesbi.ttf ]
\let\hbar\relax
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section {Test}
This is a test \(x+y\), and so is this
\[ \sum_{i=1}^{3 \cdot 9 \cdot \infty} \sin(\alpha^\varphi). \]
\end{document}
```

This does not work as expected; some Computer Modern fonts are used (CMR7 and CMR10 reported by Adobe Reader).

I am not familiar with LuaLatex, and know nothing about how fonts are handled.
Is something like this supposed to work?
That is, is is meant to be possible to use a TrueType (or OptenType) font for the main text, and the mtpro2 fonts (made for "classical" Latex and Tex) for maths?
If, so, how do I fix the example above?

I'm using LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (rev 4971).
I don't experience similar problems with using mtpro2 with classical latex.

---

Added:
The (lite version of) mtpro2 fonts can be downloaded for free from http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html, and the Times New Roman fonts come with Windows (and can be downloaded as part of the msttcorefonts bundle on other systems).

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`?

Comment: @egreg, wow that works, thanks! (In fact, I did try it when loading mtpro2 and fontspec in the other order.. but that did not work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your input changing the loading of `fontspec` into

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
```

(and using a Times font I have on my machine, which should be irrelevant); this is the report by `pdffonts` without `no-math`

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
RBXLVL+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT        CID TrueType      yes yes yes      4  0
JNQZZL+TimesNewRomanPSMT             CID TrueType      yes yes yes      5  0
NCNXRQ+MT2MIT                        Type 1            yes yes no       6  0
IEVEFP+CMR10                         Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
BUTJUU+CMR7                          Type 1            yes yes no       8  0
RZPWYL+MT2SYS                        Type 1            yes yes no       9  0
HKHXMI+MT2EXA                        Type 1            yes yes no      10  0
PSYLOK+MT2MIS                        Type 1            yes yes no      11  0
```

and this is the output with the `no-math` option:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
RBXLVL+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT        CID TrueType      yes yes yes      4  0
JNQZZL+TimesNewRomanPSMT             CID TrueType      yes yes yes      5  0
ZBRPMB+MT2MIT                        Type 1            yes yes no       6  0
EOOYOL+MT2SYT                        Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
GWFJLO+MT2MIS                        Type 1            yes yes no       8  0
JLPQZM+MT2SYS                        Type 1            yes yes no       9  0
HKHXMI+MT2EXA                        Type 1            yes yes no      10  0
```

Comment: Can my (fixed) example be considered "correct" use? (or, is it a "hack") That is, when using fontspec, should all fonts be loaded through it? I guess what I really ask is: should I expect that something breaks with a larger example?

Comment: @hal46 No, it's perfectly fine to use “native” math fonts.

Comment: use `unicode-math` to set the mathfonts: `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and `\setmathfont{Math Time Professional 2}`. ALso note that you do not have to supply al the ttfs. Using `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` should be enough.

Also there are to great alternatives two the windows specific fonts: use Tex Gyre Termes and Tex Gyre Termes Math.

Comment: @MaxNoe, mtpro2 is not an OpenType math font! (Following your instructions for loading mtpro2 I get a "font-not-found" error message.)

Comment: Mybad, but what about the Tex Gyre Fonts. They should be delivered with texlive and miktex

Comment: @MaxNoe There is TeX Gyre Termes Math, but, in my opinion, it's much inferior to MathTime Pro.